# Showing Data in React Native with useParams

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I've the following question, how can I display the data in react-native with useparams? I've the following code snippet in my Details.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

const Details = () => {

    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    const token = userData ? userData.accessToken : null

    const params = useParams()
    const [load, setLoad] = React.useState(false)

    const getAccountDetails = React.useCallback(async () => {
        setLoad(true)
        await fetch (`http://localhost:4000/api/account/findonecard/${params.idCard}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
            //My response drops the data I need
        })
      }, [])

      React.useEffect(() => {
        getAccountDetails()
      }, [getAccountDetails])
      

  return (
    <>
    <div>Details</div>
      {
        !load ? 
        (
          <Detail card={{
            username: card.fullname,
            description: card.description,
            mainPic: card.pic_profile,
            userTags: card.usertags
          }} />
        )
        :
        (
          <div style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: 99, color: '#000000', fontFamily: 'sans-serif', textAlign: 'center', margin: '60px auto' }}>No Card to show</div>
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Details
```

This releases an object with my data, such as photo, description, name, etc.
Although I tried to loop through the object, I can't display the data on my Front, what am I missing?

This is my Detail.jsx

```
const Detail = ({ card }) => {

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <div className="content_card-container">
        <ShowMore/>
         <h2 className="content_card-username">{card.username}</h2>
        <div
          className="content_card-image"
          style={{
            backgroundImage:
              `url(${card.cardImg})`
          }}
        />
        <div className="content_tags-slider">
          <SliderComponent tags={card.userTags} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="content_user-description">
        <p className="content_user-description-text">{card.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="content_choice-container">
        <img src={Dislike} alt="" className="content_choice-icon" />
        <img src={Like} alt="" className="content_choice-icon" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you sure this is about React Native? You're not using React Native components?

Comment: @RubenSmn Yes, I'm sure, oh well, my coworkers told me that we are working with React Native

Comment: [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) looks a little different, this is using [ReactDOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) for the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep track of the **account details** we'll create a state.

```js
const [accountDetails, setAccountDetails] = useState({});
```

In the `getAccountDetails` function you can set the state with the received data from the api. You're also *mix 'n matching* `await` and `then`, you should use one. Lets go with `await` for this one

```js
const getAccountDetails = React.useCallback(async () => {
  setLoad(true);
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:4000/api/account/findonecard/${params.idCard}`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  // console.log(data);
  setAccountDetails(data);
  setLoad(false); // set load to false
}, []);
```

When passing the card data down to the `Detail` component we can use the `accountDetails` like so

```js
<Detail
  card={{
    username: accountDetails.fullname,
    description: accountDetails.description,
    mainPic: accountDetails.pic_profile,
    userTags: accountDetails.usertags,
  }}
/>
```

You maybe want to set the initital state of `load` to true